# Freemarker TOTAL (of numbers in a list) in Netsuite

Tags: html, freemarker, netsuite

In the **Item list** on sales orders, we have a column that displays different numbers, i.e;

```
CODE            COLUMN X
Item A              3
Item B              5
Item C              1
Item D              10
```

I can't use suitescript or java or any type of coding on the Sales Order-side,
so I need a way to calculate the **total of column X** within the PDF/HTML template (in Freemarker)

FYI: The format of the fields in column X is 'Decimal Number'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your column is called `custcol_columnx`, you can do the following:

```
<#assign total = 0>
<#list record.item as item>
  <#assign total = total + item.custcol_columnx>
</#list>

Total: ${total}
```

Comment: Note that instead of `<#assign total = total + item.custcol_columnx>` you can write `<#assign total += item.custcol_columnx>` (since FreeMarker 2.3.23).

Comment: @ddekany Noted, though Netsuite provides version 2.3.19 I believe at the moment, so not an option at this stage.

Comment: 2.3.19 is more than 5 years old... it's sad if they still ship with that, since 2.3.x versions aim 100% backward compatibility.